# Matrix derivative of $\hat{G}\ln \hat{G}$ where $\hat{G}$ is a diagonalizable matrix?

Tags: matrices, derivatives

Let $\hat{G}$ be a $n\times n$ matrix that is diagonalizable $\hat{D}=P^{-1}\hat{G} P$. What is the matrix-by-matrix derivative:

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} \hat{G}\ln \hat{G}
$$

---

My intuition would be to proceed as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} \hat{G}\ln \hat{G}&=\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} \hat{G} \right)\ln \hat{G}+\hat{G}\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} \ln \hat{G}\\
&=\ln \hat{G}+\hat{G}\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} P^{-1} \ln \hat{D} P\\
&=\ln \hat{G}+ \left[ \hat{G} \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} P^{-1} \right) \ln \hat{D} P \right] + \left[\hat{G} P^{-1} \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}}   \ln \hat{D} \right) P \right]+ \left[\hat{G} P^{-1} \ln \hat{D} \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}}   P \right]
\end{align}
$$

What can I simplyfy from there? Can $\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} P^{-1} \right)$ or $\left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} P \right)$ be made equal to $0$?

What about the middle term $P^{-1} \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}}   \ln \hat{D} \right) P$?

$$
P^{-1} \left( \frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}}   \ln \hat{D} \right) P=P^{-1} \left( \frac{1}{\hat{D}} \frac{\partial \hat{D}}{\partial \hat{G}} \right) P
$$

---

I imagine that because $\hat{G}$ is diagonalizable, eventually

$$
\frac{\partial }{\partial \hat{G}} \hat{G}\ln \hat{G} \to \ln \hat{G} +1
$$

but I cannot seem to get there.

Comment: when you derive with respect to a matrix you should obtain a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix..
please, report your definition of derivative

Comment: @Exodd I am using matrix-by-matrix derivative from https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf page 8

Comment: The book and I are saying the same thing: if you derive a Function of matrices (like $tr(A)$) you obtain a matrix. If you derive a matrix by an entry you still obtain a matrix. But if you derive a matrix by a matrix you obtain a larger matrix

Comment: @Exodd surely $\partial \hat{G} / \partial \hat{G}$ is the identity matrix... are you saying it is a $n^2 \times n^2$ identity matrix?

Comment: $\partial Tr(X) /\partial X = I$

Comment: Where did you find this problem?

Comment: @Exodd I am trying to construct a definition of the entropy using matrices

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99873/discussion-between-exodd-and-alexandre-h-tremblay).

Comment: You keep asking about an expression for $\frac{\partial G}{\partial G}$, so here it is.  It's a 4th order tensor, so I'll use index notation
$$\frac{\partial G_{ij}}{\partial G_{pq}}=\delta_{ip}\delta_{jq}={\cal E}_{ijpq}$$
This does not equal the identity matrix. In fact, it's a twisted tensor product of **_two_** identity matrices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $X, Y$ are Banach spaces (such as $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$) and $F:X\to Y$, then the derivative $DF(a)$ of $F$ at $a \in X$ is a linear map from $X$ to $Y$. The map $DF$ comes from the asymptotic form

$$ F(a+x) = F(a) + DF(a)x + o(\|x\|) \tag{*}$$

Any other representations of derivative (such as using numbers to write the derivative of $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ or using matrices to denote the derivative of $F : \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$) come from this definition plus suitable identifications of linear maps with other objects.

Now in the case of function $F:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, we may either vectorize $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ to identify $n\times n$ matrices with $n^2$-vectors or go through with the original definition of $DF$. But in the end, any such representation of derivative must conform to $\text{(*)}$.

The definition $\text{(*)}$ helps us identify the derivative of the map $F(A) = A\log(A)$. To make matrix logarithm well-defined, we assume that $F$ is defined on the space of $n\times n$ real diagonalizable matrices with positive eigenvalues. We also consider linear maps $M_{A}$, $M_{A}^{*}$, and $\operatorname{ad}_A$ defined by

$$ M_{A}(X) = AX, \qquad M_{A}^{*}(X) = XA, \qquad \operatorname{ad}_A(X) = AX - XA.$$

Then for any $n\times n$ matrix $X$ with sufficiently small matrix norm, by the [Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula), with $\psi(s) = \frac{s}{1 - e^{-s}}$ and $\psi(0) = 1$,

\begin{align*}
\log(A+ X)
&= \log(e^{\log A}e^{\log(I+ A^{-1}X)}) \\
&= \log A + \psi(\operatorname{ad}_{\log A}) (\log(I + A^{-1}X)) + \mathcal{O}(\|X\|^2) \\
&= \log A + \psi(\operatorname{ad}_{\log A}) (A^{-1} X) + \mathcal{O}(\|X\|^2).
\end{align*}

So it follows that

$$ (A+X)\log(A+X) = A \log A + X \log A + A \psi(\operatorname{ad}_{\log A}) (A^{-1} X) + \mathcal{O}(\|X\|^2). $$

From this, we conclude that the derivative of $F(A) = A\log A$ at $A$ is the linear map

$$ DF(A) = M_{\log A}^{*} + M_{A} \psi(\operatorname{ad}_{\log A}) M_{A}^{-1}. \tag{1}$$

---

**Example 1.** As a sanity check, consider the case where $X$ commutes with $A$, i.e. $[A,X] = 0$. Then from $\operatorname{ad}_{\log A}X = 0$, we get $\psi( \operatorname{ad}_{\log A})(A^{-1}X) = A^{-1}X$ and hence

$$ DF(A)X = (\log(A) + I)X. $$

So $\text{(1)}$ reduces to the well-known formula $(x \log x)' = \log x + 1$.

**Example 2.** Let

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

Then by using the fact that $N := A + \epsilon X - I$ is idempotent for any $\epsilon$, we get

$$ \log(A + \epsilon X) = \log (I + N) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}N^n = (\log 2)N. $$

From this, we directly compute that

$$ DF(A) X = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{F(A+\epsilon X) - F(A)}{\epsilon} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \log 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

On the other hand, it is straightforward to check

$$ (\log(A) + I)X = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1+\log 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}. $$

This shows that $DF(A)$ cannot equal the multiplication by $\log(A)+I$.

Comment: In equation (1), are the maps $M^{*}_{\log A}$, $M_A$ and $M_A^{-1}$ maps of $X$ (as defined above)? Or perhaps are they map taking as inputs the identity matrix, such as $M^{*}_{\log A}[I]=\log A I$. What is $M_A^{-1}$ explicitly --- is the negative one exponent on the $A$ or on the $M_A$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay, $M_A$ is the left-multiplication by $A$, which is independent of $X$. So $M_A(X)$ is basically a complicated way of writing $AX$. (The advantage of considering $M_A$ is that this allows to embed the space of matrices into the space of operators between matrices. Once you get used to this machinery, you may abuse notation to write $A$ in place of $M_A$.) Then $M_{A}^{-1}$ is its inverse, hence is the same as $M_{A^{-1}}$ which is the left-multiplication by $A^{-1}$. Similar comments apply to $M^{*}$.

Comment: In the definition of my question, I mentioned that the matrix are diagonalizable. Is this property sufficient to state that $D (A\log A) = \log A +1 $?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay, Check my edit, especially the second example.

Comment: So I gather that there is some freedom regarding picking the value of X? For instance, one could pick X to also be diagonal, in which case $[A,X]=0$. X here is equivalent to picking the "direction" of the derivative? If so, are you not picking X along the direction of A which does not vary?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay, Indeed, $DF(A)X$ corresponds to the directional derivative of $F$ at $A$ along the direction $X$. But this does not require that the direction $X$ (or in a more fancy term, 'tangent vector') lie in the same space. Moreover, in Example 2, notice that $A+\epsilon X$ is diagonalizable for each $\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}$ (since the eigenvalues are distinct), so it perfectly makes sense to consider $F(A+\epsilon X)$ and consequently $DF(A)X$.

Comment: In my example, I am deriving $A \ln A $ with respect to $A$. Does that restrict the $X$ in any way, for instance, to also be $A$? In this case, we consider $F(A+\epsilon A)$ and therefore since $[A,A]=0$ consequently $\partial (A\log A) / \partial A = \log A+1$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay, Any widely used definitions of derivative (Fréchet derivative, Gateaux derivative, etc) do not work that way, but if you think you are working with an idiosyncratic notion of derivative that is different from the usual ones, please provide the relevant definitions so that we can talk without any ambiguity. The cookbook in OP's link only alludes this point (and even did not mention the exact definition), and so, I find it very unsatisfactory for such purpose.

Comment: I am not sure I follow your last comment. You have defined the derivative of $A$ with respect to $X$. We may write $\partial A / \partial X$. In your second example, you picked a $A$ which is diagonal and a $X$ which isn't. However, in my specific example, I am asking for $\partial (A \log A)/ \partial A$ and not $\partial (A \log A)/ \partial X$. Consequently, can I pose $X=A$ in your definition of the matrix derivative to solve $\partial (A \log A)/ \partial A$?

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay, I computed the total derivative (Fréchet derivative) of $F(A)=A\log(A)$, which is $\text{(2)}$. If I simply write $T=DF(A)$, then this $T$ is a linear operator $T:\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ such that $$\forall X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, \qquad (A+X)\log(A+X)=A\log(A)+T(X)+o(\|X\|)$$ holds. If you wish, you may identify $n\times n$ matrices as $n^2$-vectors and then $T$ is nothing but a $n^2\times n^2$ matrix.

Comment: @AlexandreH.Tremblay, In Example 2, I showed that $T$ is different from the multiplicative map $$M_{\log(A)+I) : X \mapsto (\log(A)+I)X$$ by choosing a suitable $X$ in the tangent space at $A$. My choice of $X$ is valid because the space of all diagonalizable matrices form an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and so, its tangent space is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ itself. (This simply reflects the fact that if $A$ is diagonalizable and $X$ is any matrix with sufficiently small norm, then $A+X$ is also diagonalizable.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99923/discussion-between-sangchul-lee-and-alexandre-h-tremblay).

Answer (score 1):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\l{\lambda} \def\lj{\l_j} \def\lk{\l_k}
\def\E{E_{ij}} \def\G{G_{ij}} \def\R{R_{jk}} \def\P{P^{-1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial} \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$The function of a diagonalizable matrix is the province of
the $\sf Daleckii\;Krein\;Theorem$

$\big[\,$In the following, $(\odot)$ denotes the Hadamard product$\,\big]$
$$\eqalign{
G &= PD\P \qiq D = \Diag{\lk} \\
F &= f(G) \\
dF &= P \BR{R\odot\LR{\P\,dG\:P}}\P \\
\\
\R &= \begin{cases}
{\Large\frac{f(\lj)-f(\lk)}{\lj-\lk}} \qquad {\rm if}\;\lj\ne\lk \\
\\
\qquad f'(\lk) \qquad\quad\; {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$
$\sf NB\!:$ In the current problem
$$\eqalign{
f(z) &= z\log(z),\qquad f'(z) = \o + \log(z) \\\\
}$$
All components of the single entry matrix $\E$ are zero, except for the
$(i,j)$ component which is equal to one.  It also happens to equal the component-wise self-gradient of a matrix
$$\eqalign{
\grad{G}{\G} &= \E \\
}$$
Substituting this into the Daleckii-Krein result yields the component-wise gradient
$$\eqalign{
\grad{F}{\G} &= P \BR{R\odot\LR{\P\E\,P}}\P \\
}$$
which is the best you can do without introducing higher-order tensors.

If you're curious, the actual gradient is a fourth-order tensor. It can be calculated as the sum of the dyadic products $(\star)$ of the componentwise gradients with the single entry matrices
$$\eqalign{
\grad{F}{G} &= \sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n \LR{\grad{F}{\G}}\star\E \\
\\
}$$
At the risk of introducing yet another type of product, the gradient can also be calculated by [vectorizing](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the Daleckii-Krein result, turning the matrix variables into (long) vectors
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\vc F}{\vc G}
 &= \LR{\P\otimes P^T}^T\:\Diag{\vc R}\,\LR{P^T\otimes\P} \\
}$$
where $(\otimes)$ is the Kronecker product.